# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I did pip install pytesseract and installed OCR too.
Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Hackry/Documents/pytest/tess.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "c:\Users\Hackry\Documents\pytest\pytesseract.py", line 6, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

My code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Users/Hackry/AppData/Local/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe' #define tesseract path

img = Image.open('C:/Users/Hackry/Documents/pytest/text.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Comment: Name of your .py file? Is it pytesseract.py? Kindly always paste the whole error,  including the initial traceback statement, it helps in solving the issue.

Comment: No I know it can't be pytesseract.py its tess.py

Comment: I see, then am not sure what's going on, give me some time, I'll try to sort it.

Comment: You have a script named `c:\Users\Hackry\Documents\pytest\pytesseract.py`, that's being imported instead of the actual module.  Rename that, and remove any `pytesseract.pyc` or similar file in the same directory.